# Get the type of the template parameter from an object, C++

Tags: c++, templates, types

Here is my simplified data structure:

### Object1.h

```
template <class T>
class Object1
{
  private:
     T a1;
     T a2;
  public:
     T getA1() {return a1;}
};
```

### Object2.h

```
template <class T>
class Object2: public Object1 <T>
{
   private:
      T b1;
      T b2;
  public:
     T getB1() {return b1;}
}
```

Is there any way to get the type `T` from an object in the following function:

### Functions.h

```
template <class Object>
void (Object *o1, Object *o2)
{
   T = o1->getA1();  // Is it possible to get T from object o1?
   // ...
}
```

Or must we give additional information about data types of both objects, like this:

```
template <class T, class Object>
void (Object *o1, Object *o2)
{
   T = o1->getA1();
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This will be possible in C++0x.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add a `using` or `typedef` statement, like this:

```
template <class T>
class Object1
{
private:
    T a1;
    T a2;
public:
    T getA1() const {return a1;}

    using type = T;
    // or
    typedef T type;
};

template <class Object>
void foo(Object *o1, Object *o2)
{
    typename Object::type x = o1->getA1();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Seeming as when the template is 'instanced?' for type T could you not, just write `T x = o1...`. I don't see why you need to typedef, when T is already a type...

Comment: +1 for the typedef, but IMHO it should be named `a1_type`, not just `type`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
template <template<class> class Object, class T>
void func1(Object<T> &o1, Object<T> &o2)
{
   T x = o1.getA1();
}
```

Working example at http://www.ideone.com/t8KON .

Btw. if you use pointers as parameters, you have to use `->` operator to call methods.