# Get type of the parameter from list of objects, templates, C++

Tags: c++, templates, types

This question follows to my previous question

[Get type of the parameter, templates, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056664/get-type-of-the-parameter-templates-c)

There is the following data structure:

Object1.h

```
template <class T>
class Object1
{
  private:
     T a1;
     T a2;
  public:
     T getA1() {return a1;}
     typedef T type;
};
```

Object2.h

```
template <class T>
class Object2: public Object1 <T>
{
   private:
      T b1;
      T b2;
  public:
     T getB1() {return b1;}
}
```

List.h

```
template <typename Item>
struct TList
{
  typedef std::vector <Item> Type;
};

template <typename Item>
class List
{
  private: 
   typename TList <Item>::Type items;

  public:
   Item & operator [] ( const unsigned int index ) {return this->items[index];}
};
```

Is there any way how to get type T of an object from the list of objects (i.e. Object is not a direct parameter of the function but a template parameter)?

Process.h

```
class Process
{
  template <class Object>
  static void process (List <Object> *objects)
  {
    typename Object::type a1 = (*objects[0]).getA1(); // g++ error: 'Object1<double>*' is not a class, struct, or union type
  } 
};
```

But his construction works (i.e. Object represents a parameter of the function)

```
template <class Object>
void process (Object *o1) 
{
    typename Object::type a1 = (*o1).getA1(); // OK
}
```

There is the main program:

```
int main()
{
   Object1 <double> o1;
   Object1 <double> o1;

   List <Object1 <double> > list;

   Process::process(&list);

}
```

Comment: That looks fine. I don't know why you're getting error.

Comment: By the way, how do you instantiate `List` class template? What type argument you pass?

Comment: Could you please post the code that you are actually trying to compile?  `objects[0].getA1()` in `process(List<Object> *objects)` is calling `List<T>::getA1()` which does not exist and the error message references `Object1<double>*` which is not mentioned anywhere.  Not to mention that `o1.getA1()` can't work because `o1` is a pointer.

Comment: Why don't you pass by reference?

Comment: Error was here. Instead of static void process (List <Object> *objects) I wrote static void process (List <Object *> *objects). Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with objects[0], where objects is a pointer. You should write that as (*objects)[0] to call operator[] of the object pointed to.

Comment: Maybe even use a reference to pass the list: `void process (List <Object> &objects)` then that problem won't arise too.

Comment: Thanks, error was here. Instead of static void process (List <Object> *objects) I wrote static void process (List <Object *> *objects).